# document.ready not working when clicked on anchor

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails

I have the navigation menu with `<a>`tags.

Now if I reload the page using browser refresh button, jQuery dom ready(`$(document).ready(function() {}`) method is being invoked.

But if I click on navigation links, that time jQuery dom ready(`$(document).ready(function() {}`) method is not invoked.

If it helps in any way, I'm using Ruby on Rails as a framework.

This is how my application.js looks like:

```
  //= require jquery
  //= require_tree
```

Comment: Looks like you forgot to include your code in the question?

Comment: There is no possible way for us to help unless you show us **your code**

Comment: I could not include the code, as it was part of my office work. And due to privacy policy could not upload it.
However I have solved the issue by adding onclick there.
`onclick='window.location.replace("<%= hyperlink %>");'`

I know it's not the best way to solve, however it worked for a time being.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is a result of `Turbolinks`. With `turbolinks` and most other `single page frameworks` the document.ready is called once. You should look at this SO question for a way to fix or work around it: [Rails 4: how to use $(document).ready() with turbo-links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18770517/rails-4-how-to-use-document-ready-with-turbo-links).

Let me know if I was able to help.

Comment: The use of code tags is for code. It's not something people use arbitrarily